# Target class [App\Listeners\CartUpdatedListener] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, e-commerce

i want to configure events in choping cart uses LaravelShoppingcart package, i run cmd following `php artisan make: listener CartUpdateListener`, but it gives me error `Target class [App \ Listeners \ CartUpdatedListener] does not exist`.

**EventServiceProvider.php**

```
protected $listen = [
        'cart.added' => [
            'App\Listeners\CartUpdatedListener',
        ],
        'cart.updated' => [
            'App\Listeners\CartUpdatedListener',
        ],
        'cart.removed' => [
            'App\Listeners\CartUpdatedListener',
        ],
    ];
```

**CartUpdateListener.php**

```
 /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  object  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle($event)
    {
       dd("event was fired");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error tells us about `CardUpdatedListener` but your file name is `CardUpdateListener` (an extra 'd' in the word Update). Check it, or post full class code.

Answer (score 0):

When you run an Artisan command, it bootstraps a Laravel app. Among a lot of things, event listeners are setup and they need to be constructed, but at this moment, your listener class does not exist yet. Follow these steps:

- Remove everything from your `listen` property of `EventServiceProvider`
- Run `php artisan make:listener CartUpdatedListener`
- Refill your `listen` property